# Is it possible to apply audio effects and save the effects to a file in Android?

Tags: java, android, audio

I've been working on an Android application for one of my courses and have been struggling to find an easy method to apply audio effects to a recorded or uploaded audio clip. I am looking to add delay, reverb, time modification (without pitch modification), pitch modification (without time modification), and reverse. I do not want the user to change any settings and just want a basic effect without modifications.

I have looked into how EnvironmentalReverb and PresetReverb work from the AudioEffect library, but that is not the approach I want. I would like to save the effects to a temporary file rather than attaching the effect to the MediaPlayer stream. I do not see any of the aforementioned effects in the library aside from reverb and from looking around, it looks like most of the effects are written in C. Is the easiest approach to utilize the Android NDK library to use the C code or are there any Java libraries that work directly with the file instead of attaching to the MediaPlayer?